# Proving that $f(z) =(2z-z̅ )z̅$ is differentiable at $z = 0$ using the definition of derivative.

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, derivatives

Hello I'm currently stuck on solving the derivative of $f(z) = (2z - \bar{z})\bar{z}$. I'm getting stuck at solving $\frac{(2z-\bar{z})\bar{z}}{z}$ as $z \rightarrow 0$

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\dfrac{\overline z}z$ is bounded and $\lim_{z\to0}2z-\overline z=0$,$$\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\left(2z-\overline z\right)\overline z}{z}=\lim_{z\to0}\left(2z-\overline z\right)\frac{\overline z}z=0.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you explain what you mean when you say $\frac{\bar{z}}{z}$ is bounded?

Comment: For each $z\neq0$, $\left|\frac{\overline z}z\right|=1$.

Comment: Thank you. So this implies that the limit is 0?

Comment: An alternate way to write the argument is: $$\left|\frac{\left(2z-\overline z\right)\overline z}{z}-0\right|= \left|2z-\overline z\right| \left|\frac{\overline z}{z}\right| = \left|2z-\overline z\right| \to 0$$

Comment: @Abteen Yes, because if $\lim_{z\to z_0}g(z)=0$ and $h$ is bounded, then $\lim_{z\to z_0}g(z)h(z)=0$.

Comment: Thank you both!

Comment: This is a separate but similar question. How would one calculate the same limit for $\frac{e^{\bar{z}} - 1}{z}$